# Using pthread_yield to return control over the CPU back to Kernel

Tags: pthreads, kernel, posix, interrupt

Consider the following scenario:
in a POSIX system, some thread from a user program is running and timer_interrupt has been disabled.

to my understanding, unless it terminates - the currently running thread won't willingly give away control over the CPU. 
My question is as follows: will calling **pthread_yield()** from within the thread give the kernel control over the CPU?

any kind of help with this question would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning off the operating system's timer interrupt would change it into a cooperative multitasking system. This is how Windows 1,2,3 and Mac OS 9 worked. The running task only changed when the program made a system call.

Since pthread_yield results in a system call, yes, the kernel would get control back from the program.

If you are writing programs on a cooperative multitasking system, it is *very important* to not hog the CPU. If your program does hog the CPU the entire system comes to a halt.

This is why Windows MFC has the idle message in its message loop. Programs doing long term tasks would do it in that message handler by operating on one or two items and then returning to the operating system to check if the user had clicked on something.

Comment: Not really cooperative, no. A hardware interrupt from one of the many other drivers could still request a scheduling run and generate a context-change that causes running threads to be preempted.

Comment: @MartinJames: I am not positive but I believe that happened in Windows 3 as well.

Comment: Win3 was indeed cooperative and so pretty hopeless.  Preemptive multitasking first appeared with W95, greatly improving I/O performance, (but not stability, as we all know:).  Windows got to the, (very), low point with the apalling ME. With NT/W2K, Windows got the stability of 32-bit protected mode and the high-performance I/O of preemptive multitasking, making it sensibly useable.

Comment: 'If your program does hog the CPU the entire system comes to a halt' - no, it does not have to, because of the other hardware interrupts.  I'm tempted to downvote for that, but I'm in a good mood today:)

Comment: @MartinJames: You did use Win 3.1 didn't you? If you developed for it you know the entire system came to a halt if you got a stuck loop. Ctrl-Alt-Delete was the only way to save you. Now, *technically* I suppose the disk interrupts were still running but it made no practical difference.

Comment: Windows 3.x used a combination of cooperative multitasking and preemptive multitasking. Time was shared between native Windows programs cooperatively, but between DOS programs preemptively.

Comment: W3.1, yes.  Since W95, it has made a huge difference that the other interrupts are available.  I'm assuming that the OP is asking about later OS than W3.1!  The most noticeable effect of masking the timer interrupt on those later OS would be that system calls with timeouts would not time out and that would surely generate big problems, but the system would not revert to cooperative multitasking - preemption would still take place upon completion of I/O requests.

Answer (score 2):

It can easily relinquish control by issuing system calls that perform blocking inter-thread comms or requesting I/O.  The timer interrupt is not absolutely required for a multithreaded OS, though it is very useful for providing timeouts for such system calls and helping out if the system is overloaded with ready threads.

Comment: Hello Martin.
Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.
To my understanding, In UNIX, The system routine in charge of rescheduling is **schedualer_tick()** which is called from the **timer_interrupt**.
If the timer_interrupt is disabled – will calling **pthread_yield()** result in giving control over the CPU to the kernel? This way allowing  a new process to use the CPU?

Comment: @guy.gc - it may do, or it may not.  If there are fewer ready threads than cores, yield() is likely to just return without changing anything.  The timer interrupt only really affects scheduling when there are more ready threads than cores or, more likely on the majority of systems that are not oveloaded, when some I/O, inter-thread synchro or Sleep system call times out.  Note that, on most systems, the timer interrupt is just one of many interrupt-driven drivers that can request a scheduling run.